# How to increase the performance of my website in Drupal 7

Tags: 7, performance

I have tested my website on http://www.webpagetest.org/, and I found my website performance is very bad. I have used minifying of CSS and JavaScript, and reducing the pic size; performance is still very bad.
How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Your question is very broad and I think you could do some homework first. A lot has already been written about this. Have you searched? What did you find? What did you try and how did it work for you? Have you even visited /admin/config/development/performance on your site?

Comment: [APC](http://drupal.org/project/apc)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can guess all you want and experiment, but the only way to actually achieve meaningful results is to profile the system to figure out where the bottlenecks are.   There are many ways to accomlish this.

You can use the [Performance](http://drupal.org/project/performance) module to identify slow pages.

You can use [xhprof](http://pecl.php.net/package/xhprof) and the [Devel](http://drupal.org/project/performance) module to identify memory problems, and show slow functions and queries.

Are you running [APC](http://us.php.net/apc)?  If not, you should.  Stick the apc.php file somewhere safe and check the statistics to make sure you don't have cache churn.

Install [DB Tuner](http://drupal.org/project/dbtuner) and see what the [mysqltuner](http://mysqltuner.pl/mysqltuner.pl) results and recommendations are, particularly with regards to buffer sizes and query cache size.

You can also read up on [profiling and optimizing Apache](http://www.google.com/search?q=profile+and+optimize+apache)

You could also experiment with [Zend Server CE](http://www.zend.com/en/products/server-ce/) as it includes a PHP optimizer in addition to opcode caching.

Comment: "Stick the apc.php file somewhere safe" --> how?

Comment: Essentially, protect it with .htaccess.  Put in a password protected directory, or put in a <Files> and restrict it to your IP, or use any of the other access restrictions that Apache provides.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what MPD writes: before you have a look at tools that complement Drupal, have a look at the settings in Drupal. Make sure you enable caching and CSS/Js aggregation on /admin/config/development/performance.

Also check your theme settings: some themes (like Zen) have a developer mode which forces the theme registry to be rebuilt on every page load, which can be handy for developing, but a huge performance hit at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Minify](https://drupal.org/project/minify) module. Minify module minify the JavaScript using Google compiler. It also works with "Boost" and "Aggregate JavaScript files" so you can also get advantage of combining multiple JavaScript files which is default option in Drupal 7.

Minify module also minify HTML.