# What D7 settings need changed to take advantage of bigger cloud server

Tags: performance, database

I've just upgraded my Rackspace cloud server to 2GB in hopes of speeding up my site. What steps should I now take to enable my Drupal site to utilize this extra memory?

Php mem is to 512MB at present. This is as far as I have gone in changed things (could I go higher, should I?)These are the types of questions I have..

Comment: Keep in mind that the PHP memory limit is for a single execution; you likely don't have any pages that require 512 MB of Ram, and if you do, you'd better hope they aren't public facing. You really want PHP to deliver your pages more leanly. Use opcode caching (APC, etc), use a faster server (Litespeed is awesome), and get rid of contributed modules that you don't need/aren't using/can do manually in a small module or in your theme.

Answer (score 2):

[Varnish](http://drupal.org/project/varnish), [Memcache](http://drupal.org/project/memcache), & [APC](http://pecl.php.net/package/APC) come to mind. PHP either has enough memory or it doesn't; giving it 512MB wont speed it up.

Answer (score 2):

You need to profile your system.  Any other changes, including resizing your instance are totally guesses.  I have some suggestions for profiling in my answer to [How to increase the performance of my website in Drupal 7](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/15699/how-to-increase-the-performance-of-my-website-in-drupal-7-9/15708#15708).  @marcvangend's answer also has suggestions on Drupal specific settings.